# Storing datatypes and embedding them in other datatypes

Tags: powershell

I can store a data type in a variable like this

```
$type = [int]
```

and use it like this:

```
$type.GetType().Name
```

but, how can I embed it in another declaration? e.g.

```
[Func[$type]]
```

*** Update I ***

so the `invoke-expression` will do the trick (thanks Mike z).  what I was trying to do is create a lambda expression.  this is how I can do it now:

```
$exp = [System.Linq.Expressions.Expression]
$IR = [Neo4jClient.Cypher.ICypherResultItem]
Invoke-Expression "`$FuncType = [Func[$IR]]"
$ret = $exp::Lambda($FuncType, ...)
```

but also thanks to @PetSerAl and @Jan for interesting alternatives

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19849848/powershell-how-to-create-a-delegate contain what you're looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does not appear to be possible directly, at least according to the [PowerShell 3.0 specification](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36389).

The `[type]` syntax is called a *type-literal* by the spec and its definition does not included any parts that can be expressions. It is composed of *type-names* which are composed of *type-characters* but there is nothing that is dynamic about them.

Reading through the spec, I noticed that something like this however works:

```
$type = [int]
$try = Read-Host
$type::"$(if ($try) { 'Try' } else { '' })Parse"
```

Now you might wonder why `$type::$variable`  is allowed. That is because `::` is an operator who's left hand side is an expression that must evaluate to a type. The right hand side is a *member-name* which allows simple names, string literals, and use of the subexpression operator.

However PowerShell is extremely resilient and you can do almost anything dynamicly via `Invoke-Expression`. Let's say you want to declare variable that is a generic delegate based on a type you know only at runtime:

```
$type = [int] # This could come from somewhere else entirely
Invoke-Expression "`$f = [Func[$type]]{ return 1 }"
```

Now `$f` has your delegate. You will need to test this out if $type is some complex nested or generic type but it should work for most basic types. I tested with `[int]` and `[System.Collections.Generic.List[int]]` it worked fine for both.

Answer (score 2):

It can be achieved by reflection:

```
$type = [int]
$Func = [Func``1] # you have to use mangled name to get generic type definition.
$Func.MakeGenericType($type)
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I don't thing you can do this. Have a look at this question [Is possible to cast a variable to a type stored in another variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464765/is-possible-to-cast-a-variable-to-a-type-stored-in-another-variable).

There is a suggestion that a conversion is possible using **Convert.ChangeType** method on objects that implement **IConvertible**, but as far as I can tell this is not implemented in PowerShell.

You can fake it a little bit, by using your stored type in a scriptblock, but this may not be what you are after.

```
$type = [byte]
$code = [scriptblock]::create("[$type]`$script:var = 10")
& $code
$var.gettype()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                                                                  
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                                                                  
True     True     Byte                                     System.ValueType
```